# Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class org.apache

Tags: android, warnings

guys. 
I get these errors(504 of them):

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$7) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

I put that in proguard

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod
-dontoptimize
```

However, I still get this errors. I use

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
dependencies {
     compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
}
```

Everything works fine, these errors appears only when I generate apk. But APK works fine. How can I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Add below attributes to pro-guard file

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
```

Comment: That solves the release build, but what about debug build?